# Truncated text from NFC tag

Tags: nfc

The NTAG216 can hold 800+ bytes of information.  But when I scan it with my Samsung S4, it will only show 5 lines of text followed by an ellipses (...) which is at most about 270 bytes.  I've tried it with 2 other Samsungs and an LG with the same result, so I think it's an Android issue. Even if you only put one character per line, it will only show five lines of text.  If I use an app it shows the full content of the tag, so I know all the content is on the tag and the hardware is reading it, Android just chooses to only show 5 lines.

I need the phone (any NFC phone) to show the entire contents of the tag, and I need it to work without using an app.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need it to work without an app? Phones that have NFC usually have a built-in NFC reader, but those are also apps.

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation of the Tags app that is included in Android by default. The Tags app will display at most 5 lines of text for any text-type NDEF record. You can't get around this limit as it is [hard-coded](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Tag/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/res/layout/tag_text.xml#27) into the Tags app. Consequently, you won't get around using a customized app for that purpose.

Comment: What a pity that OP did not accept this answer :-(  Take my upvote